# How to dynamically pass property

Tags: typescript

I have the following function. When this function triggers action is being passed as an argument to this function. I want to use the action parameter to dynamically call a property.

The following is where I'm stuck.

```
onChange(event: any, id: number, action: any){
     this.action[id]["Selected"] = true
}
```

If I have to manually do it, it will look something like this.

```
  onChange(event: any, id: number, action: any){
    if( action == "StatutoryReq"){
      this.StatutoryReq[id]["Selected"] = true
    } else if( action == "StatutoryReqErp2007"){
      this.StatutoryReqErp2007[id]["Selected"] = true
    }
  }
```

Comment: please provide minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript/Typescript,

```
obj.some_fn
```

is same as

```
obj['some_fn']
```

So you should be able to use `this[action]`.

```
onChange(event: any, id: number, action: any){
     this[action][id]["Selected"] = true
}
```